# Image as Button Backgrounds - CRASH and Working

Tags: android, image, button, crash, runtime

I have been through a dozen examples of this, a dozen errors relating to this, and for some reason my images dont work.

All images are less than 800x800 pixels, and less than 200kb, and all in .png format.

I have several fragments with several images in each fragment.
I have added buttons with background images as below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please select" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/broad_btn"
        android:layout_width="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
        android:background="@drawable/broad"
        android:tag="broad"
        android:text="Broad" />
    </Linearlayout>
```

Now the image on the second fragment I have is no different from the one above.
However my app crashes when I try to use it in the background.

However if I use the "problem" image on the first page - then it works fine.
It is only when I move this image unto the second fragment that it fails.

The code for the second is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/late_btn"
        android:layout_width="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
        android:background="@drawable/late"
        android:text="Long" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,

It is a RAM issue simply... hadnt paid enough attention to resource allocation.

Thanks,
U.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are getting `OutOfMemory` error for large resolution of image.

Try using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library to handle `large` photo `efficiently` and also for disk `caching`.

**Glide:**

```
GlideApp.with(context).load(R.drawable.broad).into(imageView);
```

**Picasso:**

```
icasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.late).into(imageView);
```

Hope this will help~